# Angular 8, How can I send the userinformation I recieve from a http call in a service with subscribe to another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular8

I am relatively new to Angular8 (2).

How can I send **userInformation** to another component called settings and display it on the page? and if something changes update automatically.

Any help much appriciated.

```
export interface UserInfoModel {

id: string;
email?: string;
firstName?: string;
lastName?: string;
mobile?: string;
createdAt: string;

}

private userInformation: UserInfoModel;

this.http
  .post<RequestResponse>(`${API_BASE_URL}user/login`, loginData)
  .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
  .subscribe(response => {
    const token = response.content.token;
    const userId = response.content.id;
    const email = response.content.email;

    // added to UserInfo
    this.userInformation = {
      id: response.content.id,
      email: response.content.email,
      firstName: response.content.firstName,
      lastName: response.content.lastName,
      mobile: response.content.lastName,
      createdAt: response.content.createdAt
    };

    this.token = token; // add token to local var
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Comment: See [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the use of a BehaviorSubject.

Create a service, then in your service; for example:

`ng g s user` where user is the name of your service.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

private userInfo = new BehaviorSubject< UserInfoModel>(null);
userInfo$ = this.userInfo.asObservable();

 .post<RequestResponse>(`${API_BASE_URL}user/login`, loginData)
  .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
  .subscribe(response => {
    //your existing code here
    this.setUserInfo(this.userInformation);


    this.token = token; // add token to local var
    this.userId = userId;
}


setUserInfo(userInfo: UserInfoModel): void {
  this.userInfo.next(userInfo);
}
```

In your component

You will inject your service in the component via dependency injection.

```
constructor(private userService: UserService){}
userInfo: UserInfoModel;
ngOnInit(){
  this.userService.userInfo$.subcribe(userInfo=>{this.userInfo = userInfo};
}
```

Comment: How can I prisist the data? when I refresh the page the value becomes null

Comment: Got it. Using localStorage for pressistance.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example using an http request to demonstrate how you can send your response to a child component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgghzt

Basically, the child component can accept incoming data by using `Input() myVar` on the child component.

If you want the child component to send messages back to the parent component, you can use `Output() myVar2`

Here is a good code example demonstrating how the child and parent communication works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example